# System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi am try to access the external exe from sql server by using CLR integration.

I am set my database `TRUSTWORTHY ON` and `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS` but am getting the following error

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure hello, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'hello': 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at HelloWorldProc.HelloWorld()
```

helloworld.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class HelloWorldProc
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void HelloWorld()
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world!\n");
        Process.Start(@"D:\Raja\trg.exe");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am got the solution for this error we want to set the **SQL Server service log on in administrator**.

**Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services**

**Find MSSQLServer service change its Log On As from local system to Administrator.**

Now I am able to open the word doc through SQL Server Procedure.